# How can I create a three column div inside a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, modulo

How can I create an N (e.g. 3) column div output inside a repeater?  For example if the items I am trying to render in my repeater are the numbers from 1 to 6 I'd like to see the following output:

```
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span></div>
<div><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span></div>
```

I think that his has something to do with the mod operator (%), but I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

Comment: What is Mod operation, show C# code

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need to show an example of what you're trying to do, or give a more detailed explanation of your goal.  And, as @sll mentioned, showing code does not hurt at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ModContext
{
    public ModContext(int first, int second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
        this.Result = this.First % this.Second;
    }

    public int First { get; private set; }

    public int Second { get; private set; }

    public int Result { get; private set; }
}

IList<ModContext> items = new List<ModContext>
    {
            new ModContext(10, 20),
            new ModContext(30, 40)
    };

this.repeater.DataSource = items;
this.repeater.DataBind();
```

ASPX:

```xml
<asp:Repeater id="repeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
     <div>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Result") %></span>
     <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "First") %></span>
     <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Second") %></span>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
     </div>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used repeaters for years, so I am going out on a limb here, but I think something like this should work:

```
  <ItemTemplate>
  <% if(Container.ItemIndex % 3 == 0) {%> <div> <% } %}
  <span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Result") %></span>
  <% if(Container.ItemIndex % 3 == 2) {%> </div> <% } %}
  </ItemTemplate>
```